# Laravel 5 Incude a non PSR-0 compliant Library via a Git Repo

Tags: git, laravel-5, psr-0

I currently have a laravel 5 project I am working on. I would like to use the following library (https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) however my question pertains to any non PSR-0 compliant library.

I would like to clone the library down into my own git repo (for maintaining that library as well as my own) then in composer.json autoload via the classmap. My question is where is the most appropriate place to include the library?

Should I create a new libraries folder next to the vendor folder and ignore that particular folder in my .gitignore of my project then just maintain the two seperately or is there a better method with Laravel 5 to accomplish this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Note **
the library I mentioned above does have a forked version that can be autoloaded but it doesn't look to be as up to date and I don't have the time / resources to custom fork that lib at the moment.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question about non-compliant PSR-0 files, but rather about including php-ews. I'm actively working on and maintaining  a fork on php-ews if you're interested. It's located here https://github.com/garethp/php-ews and it should be somewhat easier to use

Comment: Hey when I try to download your version of php-ews I get following error on the file testCreateItem.json: failed to open stream: invalid argument. Can you tell me how to fix it?